# Rails Console Killed After 15 Seconds in Production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, irb

When I run a Model.all query (e.g. Product.all) for a table with a few thousand records, the Rails console is killed after 15 seconds. Can I extend this threshold (I assume) or in another way run my query without exiting IRB?

I only have this problem in production. In my development environment (sqlite database) with as many records, it works just fine.

I'm running Ruby 1.9.3, Ruby on Rails 3 (with Unicorn) and use a postgres database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you load `Product.all`, it tries to load all products at once so the  process fails to allocate sufficient memory. It is a bad practice to load all product at once. Try to load products in batches. You can do something like

```
Product.find_each do { |p| p.my_awesome_work }
```

instead of using `Product.all.each {....}`

It isn't happening locally because you might have powerful computer,the computer is capable to assign that much of memory to some process which is not the case in heroku.

Comment: This was exactly it. I think the server is a bit underpowered for what we're trying to do. Maybe there is a memory leak too. ".find_each" works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably overloading the database mem usage. Do you have monit running there? Maybe monit is restarting the process based on usage.

you can issue top on another terminal screen to see the usage, also tail the rails log.

See if it gives you something like "lost connection to database"

As an aside, make sure to run the console like this in prod:

```
bundle exec rails c production -s
```

-s is sandbox

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It turned out to be a lack of RAM.

Comment: That's what I thought "You're probably overloading the database mem usage"